# Javascript clientHeight returns NaN in certain contexts

Tags: javascript, jquery, nan

Interesting issue arising for me.

I am working on an infinite scroll thing in javascript that requires getting clientHeight of a div at some point:

here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
        function init(){
            var j = 0;
            var inner1 = document.getElementById("innerDiv1");
            inner1.addEventListener("scroll", function(event){ window.j = 2; checkForLoad();});
            var inner2 = document.getElementById("innerDiv2");
            inner2.addEventListener("scroll", function(event){ window.j = 1; checkForLoad();});
        }
        var i = 0;
        var checkForLoad = function() {
            var bottomDiv;
            var bottomDivChild;
            var offsetOfDiv;
            var offsetOfPage;
            if(window.j === 2){
                bottomDiv = document.getElementById("innerDiv1");
                bottomDivChild = bottomDiv.lastElementChild;
                offsetOfDiv = bottomDivChild.offsetTop + bottomDivChild.clientHeight; //WORKS FINE
                offsetOfPage = (document.getElementById("innerDiv1").pageYOffset) + (document.getElementById("innerDiv1").clientHeight); //THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
            }
            else if(window.j === 1){
                bottomDiv = document.querySelector("innerDiv2 > div:last-child");
                offsetOfDiv = bottomDiv.offsetTop + bottomDiv.clientHeight;
                offsetOfPage = inner1.pageYOffset + inner1.innerHeight;
            }
            if(offsetOfPage > offsetOfDiv - 10) {
            alert("time to add");
            //eventually will be AJAX with XSL
                if (i % 5 !== 0) {
                    i++;
                    alert("into the append part");
                    var newResults = document.createElement("div");
                    newDiv.innerHtml = "testing " + i;
                    if(window.j === 2){
                    document.getElementById("innerDiv1").appendChild(newResults);
                    }
                    else if(window.j === 1){
                    document.getElementById("innerDiv2").appendChild(newResults);
                    }
                    checkForLoad();
                } else if (i%5 === 0) {
                    newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    newDiv.innerHTML = "Show more Results! " + i;
                    document.getElementById("scrollingDiv").appendChild(newDiv);
                    newDiv.setAttribute("ID", "showResults");
                    newDiv.setAttribute("onClick", "showMore()");
                }
            }

        };
```

I realize that there are some inconsistencies here, but they are in parts of the script i am not using. Here is the issue though, in the if(window.j === 2) statement, you can see that I use client height in a couple places. In the first one, it returns a number perfectly and life goes on as planned, but when I use it in the line where I get the "offSerOfPage", the sum becomes NaN. I am using firebug to debug it and when I add document.getElementById("innerDiv1").clientHeight to the watch list, it shows that it has a number attatched to it. Yet the sum is returned as NaN. I think my wording is a bit confusing here so if you need clarification, please ask! Thanks!

Comment: On the line with the error try this, to see if the variables have any weird typing: `console.log( typeof document.getElementById("innerDiv1").pageYOffset, document.getElementById("innerDiv1").pageYOffset, typeof document.getElementById("innerDiv1").clientHeight, document.getElementById("innerDiv1").clientHeight);`

Comment: You have this question tagged as `jQuery`, but have no jQuery code at all (which would be a lot smaller if you did go that route). Do you want a jQuery answer or was that tag a mistake?

Comment: Also, if you could provide a JSFiddle that has some sample HTML as well as the JS that would help everyone help you :)

Comment: The jquery tag was a mistake, I need to do this all in pure javascript.

Comment: Also, I added the console.log line and firebug console shows "undefined _undefined_ number 675"

Comment: @Jacob That's your issue then, undefined + number = NaN. After a quick google search it turns out pageYoffset is only defined for the window object. Use `window.pageYoffset` instead.

Comment: Fixed it, `window.pageYOffset` wasn't what i wanted (though it actually returns a number like you said) I used `document.getElementById("innerDiv1").scrollTop` and that works beautifully, thanks